# How can I prevent users from entering non-alphanumeric characters in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried using the Data Validation on the column H by applying the custom formula: `=REGEXMATCH(H1, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")`; but to no avail, Google Sheets tells me that this formula is invalid.
Back in 2020 it worked. Did Google change something?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like the sheet locale uses semicolon `;` convention instead of `,`

go with `=REGEXMATCH(A1; "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")`

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This solved it. So stupid that Google just changed its semantics while all the search on the internet pointing to the old convention using comma.